# SQL LEFT-JOIN with 2 foreign keys and merge them into one row (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys, left-join

I have following tables

Orders:

```
id | address1 | address2 | state
1  | 2        | 4        | Delivered
2  | 7        | 1        | Payment
```

Address:

```
id | city
1  | New York 
2  | Paris   
4  | London 
7  | Berlin
```

Now I need a statement to get both cities with order status.

For example order ID 1 should output: 
`Delivered | Paris | London`

I tried the following statement:

```
SELECT orders.state, address.city FROM orders
  LEFT JOIN address 
    ON orders.address1 = address.id OR orders.address2 = address.id;
```

It obviously only outputs one address city but I want both.

Any idea how the statement should look like?

Comment: Do another join for address2 and remove `OR` from on clause

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid And then how do I address the two cities?

Comment: By giving unique aliases to city columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the `self join`:

```
select o.status, ad.city, ad1.city
from Orders o 
left join Address ad on ad.id = o.address1 
left join Address ad1 on ad1.id = o.address2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to have aliases to your tables, this makes it readable.

```
SELECT o1.state, a1.city, a2.city FROM orders o1
  LEFT JOIN address a1 
    ON o1.address1 = a1.id 
  LEFT JOIN address a2
    ON o1.address2 = a2.id 
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT o.ID, (CASE WHEN o.address1 = a.id THEN a.city) as addy1, 
             (CASE WHEN o.address2 = a.id THEN a.city) as addy2 
FROM Orders as o LEFT JOIN Address as a WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

We Need to reach to the understanding that we have to deal 2 different tables rather than 1, as we want to have different result set from the same table.
Also we want the exact data , not the extra data thus opting for an Inner Join

**Solution :**

```
SELECT O.ID,AD1,A.CITY City1,  o.AD2, b.City City2, STATE FROM ORDERS O
JOIN 
ADDRS A
ON O.AD1=A.ID
JOIN ADDRS b
on  O.AD2=b.ID
```

***In Case you need the DDL and DML Scripts :***

```
create table orders
(id int , ad1 int, ad2 int,state varchar(20))

insert into orders values
(2,7,1,'Payment')

create table addrs(id int,city varchar(20))

insert into addrs values(1,'NY') 
insert into addrs values(2,'Paris')
insert into addrs values(4,'London')
insert into addrs values(7,'Berlin')

select * from orders
select * from addrs
```

Hope this answer focuses more on the concept and less on the Solution